# Ошибка "No "Release" CMake configuration found. "

Tags: qt, cmake, qt6

Выпрыгивает ошибка

```
:-1: ошибка: No "Release" CMake configuration found. Available configuration: "Debug".
Make sure that CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable matches the "Build type" field.
```

Установил новый Куте 6.2.3 , по совместительству удалил старые версии.

вот не могу на релизе эту ошибку обойти в дебаге программу собирает

cmake присудствует в двух местах в директории куте `/home/dima/Qt/Qt6.0.3/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake` и в бинах системмы `/usr/bin/cmake`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

это проблема конфигурации проекта. скорее всего при создании проекта выбиралась только дебаг конфига сборки (о чем cmake и говорит).
Проверьте настройки сборки проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]